# Android permission again and again if i am already deny the permission why it ask again and again

Tags: android, kotlin

Ask for advice because I don’t know if it’s a bug or not for android system permissions

I have two A and B permissions and requested it as a multi-permission.

1. deny A permission , deny B permission once
2. deny A permission, selected don’t ask again B permission
3. If you request permission again, only A permission is displayed .
4. If you select deny A permission, permissions listener show again
   I wonder why
   The first one is Android12, but I don’t understand the deny and not seeing it again.
   I wonder if it’s a bug or intentional that the permission request window keeps popping up when you deny permission A.

Answer (score 0):

> At the same time, your app should respect the user's decision to deny a permission. Starting in Android 11 (API level 30), if the user taps Deny for a specific permission more than once during your app's lifetime of installation on a device, the user doesn't see the system permissions dialog if your app requests that permission again.

Check google docs: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial